# ModX: Keep losing formatting when I return to edit a page

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce, modx, modx-evolution, evo

I am running Evo 1.0.4 and often add HTML to my pages content by switching off TinyMCE.

I have an issue where if I return to edit a page at a later date, the HTML markup will be stripped out. The content will still be present but just wrapped in a single `<p>` tag.

This occurs with both mark up I add manually and mark up added by TinyMCE. Oddly enough, comments I put in still remain.

Would anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix it?

Comment: did you check your valid_elements and valid_children settings?

Comment: Can you post the content of the textarea?

Comment: This issue seems to be related to IE (surprise, surprise). I have had the client switch to FF and they have not had any more issues